# java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject in java

Tags: java, android, json

I am calling an API and getting this in response

```
"{\r\n  \"wrongUserLogInIdOrPassword\": true,\r\n  \"isEmailVerificationRequired\": false,\r\n  \"displayEmail\": null,\r\n  \"isPhoneVerificationRequired\": false,\r\n  \"displayPhone\": null,\r\n  \"isUserLockedOut\": false,\r\n  \"lockedOutEndDateTime\": 0,\r\n  \"isProgressToken\": false,\r\n  \"progressToken\": null,\r\n  \"isSecondPasswordRequired\": false,\r\n  \"secondPasswordToken\": null,\r\n  \"isTwoFactorRequired\": false,\r\n  \"twoFactorToken\": null,\r\n  \"logInId\": {\r\n    \"value\": \"xxxx@gmail.com\",\r\n    \"error\": \"Wrong Login id or password\"\r\n  },\r\n  \"password\": {\r\n    \"value\": \"\",\r\n    \"error\": \"Wrong Login id or password\"\r\n  },\r\n  \"invalidData\": false,\r\n  \"somethingWentWrong\": false,\r\n  \"error\": null\r\n}"
```

then I tried to convert response in JSON object by using this

```
 v = v.replaceAll("(\r\n|\n)", "");
            return new JSONObject(v).toString();
```

I also tried to replace "\n\r" but it's not working.

can anyone help?

[image]

Comment: Which library do you use for JSON?

Comment: @Getodac i am using org.json.JSONObject

Answer (score 0):

@sourabhdevpura, I've run this code, and it works fine. Probably the problem is that the method's result (`String` from  `return new JSONObject(v).toString();`) is assigned to a variable of type `JSONObject`.

Comment: I just updated a screenshot. in the last 4 hours. I tried everything but nothing is working
https://i.stack.imgur.com/T7Wbx.png

Comment: The decrypted String already represents a json. Why you don't just return the string "v"? As I see , decryptBody returns a string, so you don't need to do new JSONObject(v)